# Delay/pause between test executions in MSTest

Tags: c#, mstest

I have a solution with multiple projects in it (C# class libraries) and I am currently testing the functionality using Test cases in MSTest. After adding more test cases I was able to observe some test cases failing often when executed in batch with the other test cases. When executing only these test cases, they will always succeed.

As I use network interfaces and system resources in the code, I think the observation has something to do with them (even I release every resource/port/connection in the end of every case by code).

To overcome these problems I was thinking about a delay/pause between different test case executions. As I have roughly about 200 test cases, I would like to avoid adding code for this to every case. Is there a possibility to tell the MSTest system to add such a delay/pause?

**Example**

MSTest Project contains Test Cases

- T1
- T2
- T3
- ...
- T200

Executing all Test Cases will result in

- T1 success
- T2 success
- ...
- Tn failed (Timeout/OutOfMemory/NullReference/UnknownError...)
- ...
- T200 success

with Tn not being the same during all executions (there are some Tn being failing often while others never failed so far, but there is no real connection, besides the Tn failing are tested late in the batch)

The actual error in the test cases is also not deterministic - it ranges from timeouts and Null references at random positions to Memory Exceptions or Unknown Errors.

Executing Tests one-by-one will result in

- T1 success
- T2 success
- ...
- T200 success

Comment: Don't use network interfaces and system resources in you tests. Wrap up the real classes in an abstraction layer interface and mock them in your tests.

Comment: actually, the project is about having abstraction layers for specific communication, so I am testing the abstraction in these test cases

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to happen before and/or after each test then you can use:

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void Startup()
{
   // code here
}

[TestCleanup()]
public void Cleanup()
{
   // code here
}
```

However it is not recommended to depends on sleeps to make the tests pass - I would really try do find out what is the root cause of the exceptions.